# Combining regexp query with query_string elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query string as follows:

```
query_body_text = {
    "from" : 0 ,
    "size": 7000,
    "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "document_OrderName:(Mystuff) AND document_CreatedWhen:[2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00 TO 2017-01-31T00:00:00.000+00:00]"
     }
   }
 }
```

I want to be able to search the field `body_analysed` for a regular expression in these documents

I know I can phrase this as below but how do I combine this with the query above for the field of interest?

```
"query": {
    "regexp": {
      "user.id": {
        "value": "k.*y",
        "flags": "ALL",
        "case_insensitive": true,
        "max_determinized_states": 10000,
        "rewrite": "constant_score"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) to combine both the query

`should` clause works like a logical OR operator and `must` clause works like a logical AND operator

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "document_OrderName:(Mystuff) AND document_CreatedWhen:[2017-01-01T00:00:00.000+00:00 TO 2017-01-31T00:00:00.000+00:00]"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "user.id": {
              "value": "k.*y",
              "flags": "ALL",
              "case_insensitive": true,
              "max_determinized_states": 10000,
              "rewrite": "constant_score"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```